# Different order of results with glob('*', GLOB_NOSORT) vs readdir()?

Tags: php

It seems that in php, different directory scanning functions return the results in a different order.

The questions:

- Is there any reproducible logic behind the order in each function?
- Is there any way to modify the behavior of glob() to get results in the same order as with readdir()?

Functions to compare:

- `scandir($dir)` returns results in alphabetic order. Not very interesting.
- `glob($dir . '/*')` returns results in alphabetic order. Not very interesting.
- `scandir($dir, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE)` returns results "unsorted", [says the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)
- `opendir($dir)` + `readdir($handle)` returns results "in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.", [says the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php).
- `glob($dir . '/*', GLOB_NOSORT)` returns results "as they appear in the directory (no sorting)", [says the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).
- I have not verified the ordering with `DirectoryIterator` yet.

Experiments indicate that readdir() and scandir(, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE) produce the same order. I suspect that `DirectoryIterator` does the same.

But glob(, GLOB_NOSORT) does not play along. It produces a different ordering than the other functions.

The phrase in the manual, "order in which they are stored" could be understood as last modified date, but this is not more than a guess.

---

Background:

I am trying to optimize an existing function that currently uses readdir() , by using a filtered glob() instead. glob() with a filter pattern is faster than first reading the result with readdir() and then filtering it with e.g. preg_match().

The software is used/shared by a lot of people, so I don't want to surprise anyone by changing the order of files.

I suppose it does not really matter, since the order is not supposed to be relied on. But I still would like to understand why the functions behave differently.

Comment: Not sure how you are testing your "speed", but the first scan on a filesystem is almost never as fast as the second scan (at least with FreeBSD). You would have to test the scan more than once and discard the first result to get a more accurate speed.

Comment: I am testing in a real-world scenario where there is many more than one hit to the filesystem. glob() is faster, because the majority of files do not match the pattern I am looking for. And either way, the goal of this issue is to explain / understand the order of results.